# Laravel:54 use one route for the same routs

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I want two use only two route and **Get (mp3,video,album** or **artist).**

Here is my try : (in a group "/")

```
Route::get("mp3s", "PostController@archivePt");
  Route::get("mp3s/mp3/{slug}", "PostController@singlePost");

  Route::get("videos", "PostController@archivePt");
  Route::get("videos/video/{slug}", "PostController@singlePost");

  Route::get("albums", "PostController@archivePt");
  Route::get("albums/album/{slug}", "PostController@singlePost");

  Route::get("artists", "PostController@archivePt");
  Route::get("artists/artist/{slug}", "PostController@singlePost");
```

> I have writed a foreach ,But :
>
> 1. i think it's a bad practice in eachpage.
> 2. i cant get (mp3 or album ,.. ) in here :

```
  foreach (pts as  $pt) {
    Route::get( $pt.'s', 'PostController@archivePt');
    Route::get( ("{$pt}s/$pt/{slug}"), "PostController@singlePost");
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

as you are using the same controller -*which is considered as a poor practice*- , you may handle your parameters like following :

```
Route::group("media", function () {
    Route::get("{category}", "PostController@archivePt");
    Route::get("{category}/{type}/{slug}", "PostController@singlePost");
});
```

and within your methods , call those variables as :

```
public function singlePost($category, $type, $slug)
....
```

---

Comment: seems ok ! But in this url `localhost:8000/admin/post/new` 404 :(((

Comment: "as you are using the same controller -which is considered as a poor practice-" you are need to write separate controller for each group of routes, this will save you from such a errors

Comment: at least make a unique group for your `PostController` routes, for example, I've updated my answer with 'media' route group , so you will be able then to classify/group your routes easily.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Single route as well,

```
Route::get("{category}/{type?}/{slug?}", "PostController@getPost");
```

In you Post Controller

```
public function singlePost($category, $type = null, $slug = null) {


}
```

by this way you can implement, method overloading, use `switch` statement to retrieve the results, if only category comes, show the archives, if category and type comes, show list of data of that type, if all three comes retrieve the single post.